# adding multiple objects to a single key

Tags: javascript, hashmap

i want to add multiple objects to a single key in javascript
desired output :

```
{1:[{city_name:'XYZ',city_id:21},{city_name:'ABC',city_id:2}]}
```

Code snippet:

```
for(var key = 1; key <= largest ; key++ )
 {  

    for(var i =0; i<subservices.length ; i++)
    {                             
        if(key == subservices[i].from_city_order )
       {                        
            if(!(key in childMap)) {                                       
                childMap[key] =(cityIdMap[subservices[i].to_city_id]);     
            } else if(key in childMap ){                                   
              //same key value should have multiple objects in the array    
            }                                                                  
      }                                                                      
   } 
}
```

Comment: Please, add more information on `subservices`, `cityIdMap` and `childMap`.

Comment: 1.subservices is an array of objects im iterating on to fetch the city id

Comment: No, no. I mean, show its content like in JSON format.

Comment: citymap :{city_name:' ',city_id:}

Comment: [ { '3': { city_id: 3, city_name: 'Melaka', city_code: 'MLK' },
    '15': { city_id: 15, city_name: 'Seremban', city_code: 'SRB' },
    id: 165,
    from_city_id: 15,
    to_city_id: 3,
    from_city_order: 1,
    to_city_order: 2,
    is_active: 1,
    duration_in_minutes: 80 },
  { '3': { city_id: 3, city_name: 'Melaka', city_code: 'MLK' },
    '15': { city_id: 15, city_name: 'Seremban', city_code: 'SRB' },
    id: 166,
    from_city_id: 15,
    to_city_id: 3,
    from_city_order: 1,
    to_city_order: 8,
    is_active: 1,
    duration_in_minutes: 80 } ]

Comment: childmap is a map in which im trying to push multiple values against one key

Answer (score 0):

Of course you cannot have multiple objects for the same key. That's the whole point of a key-value-relationship. What you can have is maps whose values are arrays, so your map might look like this:

```
cityZipCodesMap = {
  'London' => [111,222,333],
  'NY' => [444], 
  'LA' => [555,666]
}

// With this you can do something like this:

if(!(cityName in cityZipCodesMap)){
   cityZipCodesMap[cityName] = [];
}else{
   cityZipCodesMap[cityName].push(newZipCode);
}
```